# Wordpress taxonomy with same url

Tags: wordpress

I have a taxonomy with 'rewrite'=> array( 'slug' => 'surfboards'), now if access test-xx.com/surfboards is ok, if access test-xx.com/surfboards/category-name is ok, but if access test-xx.com/surfboards/category-name/product-name return 404 error

Answer (score 0):

To achieve what you want you need to add an internal rewrite rule to handle that URL and instruct WordPress to render the page for the product with that name.

Add something like this to functions.php within your theme:

```
add_action('init', 'so40978497_rewrite_rules_array');

function so40978497_rewrite_rules_array() {

    add_rewrite_rule('surfboards/([^/]+)/([^/]+)?$', 'index.php?product=$matches[2]', 'top');
}
```

Then just visit the Permalinks admin page (under Settings) to flush the rewrite rules. After this it should be working.

As I don't know what is the name for your Product post-type, please make sure you replace 'product' with the correct post-type name, if it doesn't match your current setup.